# Incorrect pluralization on inbox notification email

Tags: bug, email, plurals

The pluralization is incorrect: "1 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox" should be "1 new item…"
[image: "1 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox" should be "1 new item..."]

Comment: [tag:status-not-important-enough].